# How do I get the current request URL (for HTTP) or script path (CLI) in a PHP extension?

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a PHP extension that needs to access the currently processed request (the request URL in case of HTTP SAPIs or the file name in case of CLI), basically `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or similar.

Ideally, I'd get the request in RINIT, but RSHUTDOWN works for me as well.

The juicy SAPI methods and variables aren't exported to extensions (which makes sense I suppose), so I tried to access the PHP `$_SERVER` variable:

`zend_hash_str_find(&EG(symbol_table), "_SERVER", strlen("_SERVER"))`

It works fine *if* the PHP script accesses it before my extension does but it's empty otherwise. I expect the contents are lazily generated on first access but I don't know how to trigger the generation.

I want my extension to be as non-invasive as possible, so I'd really like to avoid hacks like `auto_prepend_file`.

Any pointers/hints?

Comment: So, `$_SERVER` is always empty when you dump it out, or it's not set and throws an error?

Comment: Internally, the super-global variables like `$_SERVER` are referred to as "auto-globals", and are indeed only referenced when needed rather than being included in every symbol table automatically. I did some digging [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661412/157957) which may lead you in a useful direction.

Comment: @IMSoP YES! calling `zend_is_auto_global` does the trick, thanks! Feel free to make it an answer so I can accept it :)